# textjoin a prefiltered table in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, textjoin

Lets say that we have a table in excel. And someone applies a filter using ui (from the arrow in one column) to the whole table.

So from this filtered table i want to textjoin a column (the filtered rows).

Lets say we have table1 and i want to text join column Language.

if i use function

```
=TEXTJOIN(",";1;Table1[[#Data];[Language]])
```

the result joins all the rows of the column irrelevant if it is filtered, and subtotal i think can not work here.

What can i do so i can join all rows from a filtered table so everytime the filter changes the result of the textjoin will change?

So lets say that this is the column that i want to textjoin and someone filters out the first and the third row. So i want the textjoin to ignore these rows

[image]

Comment: Can you show an example of the data so we can understand the problem? If you're joining a text-formatted cell, it's unclear how that would have a negative effect on the table or the sums for your setup.

Answer (score 0):

i think this will do it:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",";1;IF(SUBTOTAL(103;OFFSET(Table1[[#Data];[Language]];ROW(Table1[[#Data];[Language]])-MIN(ROW(Table1[[#Data];[Language]]));;1))=1;Table1[[#Data];[Language]];""))
```

where the subtotal with the offseet filters out role by role if something is hidden and returns the proper fields so textjoin works

Answer (score 0):

I add a column called "Visible" to all my tables.

[Example in a table named "tabPays"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obm9r.png)

Formula for the column "Visible": `=AGGREGATE(3;5;[@Pays])`

Then it's easy to do many things related to filtered rows. The column "Visible" contains 1 when the row is visible, and 0 if not.

The answer of your question is:
`=TEXTJOIN(", ";TRUE;FILTER(tabPays[Pays];tabPays[Visible]=1))`