# offset gives 0 for empty cell excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, textjoin

I have a followup question to this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59683992/textjoin-a-prefiltered-table-in-excel).

Lets say I have an array with three columns and 4 lines like this:

ST1   ST2   INFO

1     0     one

0     1     two

0     0     three

1     1

Function

`=TEXTJOIN("; "; 1; IF(SUMPRODUCT((Table1[INFO] <> "") * (SUBTOTAL(103; OFFSET(Table1[INFO]; ROW(Table1)-MIN(ROW(Table1));0;1))));Table1[INFO];""))`

gives me all non empty cells from column INFO. But if I filter the table, the result stays the same. Why, how can I correct my formula?

Thanks.

Comment: [Read this article.](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-textjoin-function)

Comment: Textjoin in this example has TRUE to ignore empty cells. I concluded, that he problem is in function offset or/and subtotal.